# Clicking links using Capybara/Cucumber

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm attempting to set up Cucumber testing on a Jquery Mobile app, but testing clicks is throwing an unexpected error.  Here is the scenario:

problems.feature

```
Scenario: Clicking problem when not signed in
  When I go to the wall page for The Beast
  Then I should see "Blue"
  When I click the problem "Blue"
  Then I go to the sign up page
```

And the relevant step implemented to capture the second to last line is as follows:

steps.rb

```
When /^I click the problem "(.*)"$/ do |problem_name|
  find(:xpath, "//h3[text() = '#{problem_name}']/parent::a").click
end
```

Everything passes fine up until that point.  When it gets to clicking the problem, the following error is thrown:

```
When I click the problem "Blue"
  You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
  You might have expected an instance of Array.
  The error occurred while evaluating nil.each (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

I have also tried including a debugger immediately before the find().click call in steps.rb.  When I then run the find command manually, it does indeed return the following:

```
(rdb:1) p find(:xpath, "//h3[text() = 'Blue']/parent::a")
  #<Capybara::Element tag="a" path="/html/body/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a">
```

And then running in debugger with the '.click' on the end produces the following:

```
(rdb:1) p find(:xpath, "//h3[text() = '#{problem_name}']/parent::a").click
  ActionView::Template::Error Exception: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
  You might have expected an instance of Array.
  The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
(rdb:1) p find(:xpath, "//h3[text() = '#{problem_name}']/parent::a").click
  nil
```

So it appears that Capybara can find the right element, but then when attempting to click it somehow sets it to nil?  I'd like to know how I can properly execute the click that I'm looking to execute using Capybara.

Comment: have try to use: "Then show me the page" step to debug the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a problem with Capybara. Right now I have the same problem and I think the problem is that you need to use a driver for test JavaScript actions such as selenium and run your tests using this driver.

I think your button is executing the action and refreshing the page without the all the objects it need. This will not happen if you use JavaScript

Comment: You were right with the idea - specifically you need to add '@javascript' to the line above each Scenario.